# Miniclip game does not load

Tags: flash, chromium

I have Chromium and I have installed the flash player for it. The flash videos are fine, on youtube, facebook, but the miniclip game does not load. What do I have to do?

Comment: Chromium can only use flash with Pepperflash. Regular flash does not work. Explain a bit more what Miniclip is and if it works in other browsers.

Comment: @DanJohansen
I have Pepperflash installed and the 8pool page looks kile this: http://www.angrrylab.net/img/images/14217857776104334852.png

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by installing Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think PepperFlash would fix that issue I've seen other people having issues with chromium using Adobe Flash and they said PepperFlash fix most of their problems.

Install it through Ubuntu Software Center.